# Custom Square LinearLayout. How?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I create my own class for the square layout:

```
public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout{

    public SquareLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
```

Then, in my xml:

```
...
        <com.myApp.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cellImageView"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
        </com.myApp.SquareLayout>
...
```

Nothing written more in my java code.
But instead if my layout and my Image, I see only a white rectangle...

What am I wrong?

Comment: Opening tag - `<com.myApp.SquareLayout` - closing tag - `</it.appdroid.muze.SquareLayout>` ???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

// you forget to call   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);

}
```

// xml file

```
<com.example.testapplication.SquareLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cellImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  </com.example.testapplication.SquareLayout>
```

Comment: com.example.testapplication.SquareLayout is fully qualified path of SquareLayout file

Comment: Warning: this will not work with a `RelativeLayout` as the base class. I was trying to do exactly this, but with a base class of `RelativeLayout`, and the child with `centerInParent`, and it wasn't appropriately re-laying out the children. With a `LinearLayout` instead, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

I had problems calling `setMeasuredDimension` directly when applying the same technique to a RelativeLayout. I was unable to correctly align against the bottom edge. Changing to instead call up to `super.onMeasure()` with a new measure spec worked better.

```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(width, height);
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
  }
```

Comment: This is a much more flexible solution than the accepted answer as it can be used with many different superclasses aside from LinearLayout.

Comment: All available answers are similar, but have problems with measuring children's size, this is the right answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

The solution below has now been deprecated, as [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) has become the new standard and provides this functionality.

**Original Answer:**

Turns out the Android team gave us the solution, but nobody knows about it! Check out these two classes from the [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent):

- [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html)
- [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

If you want to impose the ratio of a view, you have to place it within one of these layouts. So in this case, you have to place a standard `LinearLayout`, not your subclass, within one of these layouts with the right aspect ratio. Example if you want to use a `PercentFrameLayout`:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_aspectRatio="100%">
         <!-- Whatever subviews you want here -->
     </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

And there you go, all your views will be contained within a square linear 
layout!

don't forget to add the gradle dependency `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'`  Adjust the version number as required

Comment: Aspect ratio does not seem to work unless only either width or height is defined and is defined as a fixed number (instead of `match_parent`). Using `com.android.support:percent:25.0.1`.

Comment: Both PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout are deprecated now. ConstraintLayout is recommended to use instead.

Comment: use jetpack library
    implementation "androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0"